# Turn a 1D array into nD array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 784 element 1-dimensional array that is a flattened 28x28 image.

Is there a nice, snappy, numpy/scipy procedure for translating that 784 element array into a 28x28 array?

Or do I have to do:

```
for i in range(0,28):
    for j in range(0,28):
           my_image[i,j] = oneD_vector[28*i + j]
```

Comment: have you seen numpy.reshape: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 4):

[reshape()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) works:

```
a = np.arange(784)
a.reshape(28, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks--didn't realize reshape was so versatile.